# how to create very long animation in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to create very long animation in iPhone (some visual tutorial). I know I can create animation using images but for long animation its not feasible. Any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what items you are trying to animate but from the sound of your post i think you best bet will be to actually make the animations in advance as movies and embed them into your app.

Comment: I thought the same. And I believe it is even possible to add streaming meta data to your movies that make it possible to add other interactive elements (i.e: give you way more control) while the movie is playing. This meta data is timeline based, so always in sync with your movie. Don't have an example lying around but you could try Google with this information.

Comment: I have already completed this project bye embedding the movies :)

Comment: @MiRAGe - Do you by any chance have any information about this? I'm just starting on a project where such a thing could be very very useful :)

Comment: for me it was just bells and whistles, but if you look at the MPMoviePlayerController (specifically the timedMetaData property) it is possible to add timed-meta data. From what I could find (and I didn't dive in deep) it is possible to add metadata (in the form of MPTimedMetadata) to your HTTP-stream. So I'm not sure if it also works for embedded playback video. But it's worth a shot.